# changing extensive tree game to normal representation

Tags: game-theory

I was wondering how you can get (RfM) as -0.5, -0.5

I got RrP by [(1, -1) + (1, -1)] / 2

Here is the picture of the problem:

[image]
[image]

Picture on the left: card game in extensive / tree form

picture on the right: card game in strategic form / normal representation

Answer (score 0):

RfM: with probability 0.5 you get (2,-2) and with probability 0.5 you get (-1,1)

then, the expected outcome is (1,-1)+(-1/2,1/2)=(1/2,-1/2) as you pointed in your solution

I don't see any mistake in your solution

Comment: I was a bit confused because doesn't RfM mean that you need the player needs to choose Meet? If one ends at (-1, 1) for fold, then doesnt the player not have a choice of choosing Meet?

Comment: I think it is tacitly assumed when you draw the tree that if M is not applicable, whatever appears in the leaf is the outcome

Comment: thank you so much !